# Nonblocking sockets: Are messages queued?

Tags: php, sockets, php-5.3, asyncsocket

As I understand, it is possible to create a [nonblocking](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-nonblock.php) network [socket](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-send.php) in PHP 5.x.

But what happens if a script sends several long messages using the same nonblocking socket as follow:

```
socket_write($socket, $string1, $length);
socket_write($socket, $string2, $length);
socket_write($socket, $string3, $length);
socket_write($socket, $string4, $length);
```

Are these messages queued (on the sender/receiver side?) or is it possible that the receiver gets parts of different messages because they sent "parallel"?

For example: Is is possible that the receiver gets 10 bytes of $string1, then 30 bytes of $string2, then another 25 bytes of $string1 ... and so on....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the protocol that the socket is using. See [socket_create](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) for the possible types of sockets. The main types are UDP and TCP:

> **udp**  The User Datagram Protocol is a connectionless, unreliable, protocol with fixed record lengths. Due to these aspects, UDP requires a minimum amount of protocol overhead.
>
> **tcp**  The Transmission Control Protocol is a reliable, connection based, stream oriented, full duplex protocol. TCP guarantees that all data packets will be received in the order in which they were sent. If any packet is somehow lost during communication, TCP will automatically retransmit the packet until the destination host acknowledges that packet. For reliability and performance reasons, the TCP implementation itself decides the appropriate octet boundaries of the underlying datagram communication layer. Therefore, TCP applications must allow for the possibility of partial record transmission.

To answer your question directly, TCP sockets will guarantee in-order delivery, whereas UDP sockets will not.

Comment: +1 Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432477/can-php-asynchronously-use-sockets

Comment: That means for my example above: TCP sockets will guarantee that the receiver will never see data from $string2, 3 or 4 until $string1 was received completely?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind all data is written out to the same socket, so the receiver will see the data as a single stream of information. Unless you add string lengths, delimiters, or some other information to your data, the receiver will not know where `$string1` ends and `$string2` begins.

Comment: @Justin Ethier Thats the information I was looking for! :-) Thanks a lot. I've also updated my question with an example to clarify.

Comment: @Mike: Keep in mind that this is somewhat PHP-specific. If you start multithreading (something PHP does not support, but others, like C or Java do), you have to implement mutexes (locks) on your socket to prevent this kind of weird, unexpected behavior on the receiver side.

Comment: @netcoder That's an important info because I will also create a c# socket app. That means, I have to lock a sending socket until the complete data has been sent? If so: why then not just using blocking sockets?

Comment: @Mike: If you multi-thread, a non-locked socket can potentially be accessed by two different threads at the same time, resulting in gibberish (10 bytes from thread A, then 10 bytes from thread B then 10 bytes from thread A again). Mutexes have nothing to do blocking sockets. Blocking sockets blocks (hangs) your application or thread until something happens (reception or sending of data, accepting a new connection, dropping an existing connection, etc.). Locking a socket with a mutex will prevent it from being manipulated by two threads at the same time.

Comment: My comment about locking is only important if you *multi-thread* and plan to *share* socket resources across threads.

Comment: @netcoder My C# does multi-thread and share socket resources across threads. Last question: I understand how to lock the socket, but how can I remove the lock? Should the socket fire an event when sending data is complete, which I can use to unlock the socket?

Comment: @Mike: Can't really help you there. I'm not very knowledgeable in C# (yet). Post some of your code in a new question, there are plenty of C# pros on SO. :)