# PHP listens for button/connection while "while loop" is in progress

Tags: php, loops, connection, while-loop, signals

I need to make application in PHP which will work in while loop, and listen to connection and if I send signal for stop, it will stop while loop.

For example:

```
<?PHP
set_time_limit(0);
$i=0;
while ($i <= 2000){

// Listen for connection = Kill signal
// For example:
//   if signal is received{
//   break; 
//   }

$i++; // Count
usleep(2000);
}

?>
```

So if I have web interface with stop button, I wanna be able to stop while loop when I click on that stop button.

Comment: is this possible? You most likely best way would use js since it is client-side and php is server-side.

Comment: Not possible. The php-code is evaluated on the server **before** it is being sent out.

Comment: Similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705357/how-to-listen-muliple-tcp-streams-continously-by-stream-get-contents

Possible to done it like that?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is evaluated on the server-side and therefore, client-side bindings cannot emit changes in the control flow in PHP.

Your best bet would be to implement something like this in Javascript, binding the button press to a defined event that would stop the loop there.

Comment: This is similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705357/how-to-listen-muliple-tcp-streams-continously-by-stream-get-contents

Is that possible?