# execute 2 cURL functions concurrently and randomly

Tags: php, curl

I was wondering if it was possible to concurrently execute two post_to_url functions randomly at the same time -- the post_to_url function is a cURL request and $data are variables from a form. I have tried to rewrite the post_to_url function with curl_multi handle but it did not work. thanks for the help - much appreciated.

```
$urls = array(
   "http://examplesite1.com/cgi-bin/maxuseradmin.cgi",
   "http://examplesite2?fid=6646588e54",
   "http://examplesite1?fid=2fb44e3888"
);

$data = array(
    $data2,
    $data3,
    $data4
);
$x = rand(0,2);
post_to_url($urls[x], $data[x]);
post_to_url($urls[x], $data[x]);
```

Comment: You can always try to go for multithreading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications

Comment: Or you might want to check out [async sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432477/can-php-asynchronously-use-sockets). It will probably be simpler in this case, especially if you manage to find a decent HTTP library that uses async sockets.

Comment: Hi Vatev, im sort of new to more advanced php type of things. is there a little example that can help me get on my way? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this Class

http://peecfw.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Application/com/loadable/curl/CURL_thread.php

You can call it like this

```
$cURL = new CURL();
$cURL->addSession("https://www.example.com/?data=test");
$cURL->addSession("https://www.example2.com/?data=test");
$responses = $cURL->exec();  //This array will contain all responses
$cURL->clear();
```